# Swiftui how to programatically adjust spacing between images and text?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I'm trying to get an aligned text-image pairs in swiftui programmatically. Is it possible?

[image]

I want the word "Visit" to start from the same position in both rows.

This is my code:

```
HStack{
        Image(systemName: item.leftImage) // A system image name
        Text(item.text) // A text representing the item
}
```

I know that I can add spacing to the HStack itself, but it won't fix my issue.
Since every systemimage provided by apple has a different sizing, I guess that I should programmatically somehow determine the spacing that should be instantiated between each the image to the text.

How can I do that?

Comment: u can use `Label` with custom style. Here is an [example](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/forums/swiftui/reduce-the-space-between-a-label-s-title-and-icon/22983)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend to use explicit width for image frame, this will fit any symbol automatically and make it centred

[image: demo]

```
HStack{
        Image(systemName: item.leftImage)
           .frame(width: 28)
        Text(item.text)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Give the `Image` a constant frame, like below:

```swift
HStack {
    Image(systemName: item.leftImage)
        .frame(width: 32)
    Text(item.text) // A text representing the item
}
```

Comment: It isn't quite doing what I need, it's just pushing the text a bit to the right...

Comment: What else do you need?

Comment: As mentioned above, I want all the text to start from the same position, regardless of the image size. In the example I put above, I want the "Visit" to start from the same position

Comment: Give a frame for `Image`

Comment: @RnadomG check now.

Answer (score 1):

HStack takes Vertical alignment as argument. Then the text and icon is  vertical alignment.

```
HStack(alignment: .center)
{
    Image(systemName: item.leftImage) // A system image name
    Text(item.text) // A text representing the item
}
```

To align the text, give the image a frame `width`. You need to determine they maximum width a image can take.

```
    VStack(alignment: .leading)
    {
        HStack(alignment: .center)
        {
                Image(systemName: "pause") // A system image name
                    .frame(width: 50)
                Text("Test") // A text representing the item
        }
        HStack(alignment: .center)
        {
                Image(systemName: "cloud") // A system image name
                    .frame(width: 50)
                Text("Test") // A text representing the item
        }
    }
```

[image]