# SwiftUI HStack text unaligned

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I currently have some HStacks in a List.

[image]

However, weirdly the "Attack" text is slightly more to the right than all the other fields. It might be hard to notice, but it makes everything look slightly off. Weirdly, this doesn't happen when I try to use a different icon for it, like `shield.checkerboard`:

[image]

Here is the code that I'm using for each individual cell in here:

```swift
struct StatCell: View {
    
    var title: String
    var imgName: String
    var clr: Color
    var value: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Image(systemName: imgName)
                .font(.headline)
                .foregroundColor(clr)
                .imageScale(.medium)
            
            Text(title)
                .font(.headline)
                .padding(.leading, 10)
            
            Spacer()
            
            Text("\(value)")
                .font(.headline)
                .foregroundColor(.gray)
        }
    }
}
```

I'm new to Swift and iOS development in general, so I apologize if I get any terminology wrong. If anybody knows any solutions for this issue apart from using a different icon, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: SF symbols have different size. Does this answer your questions https://stackoverflow.com/a/61984317/12299030? Additionally you can use ScaledMetric to size image when text dynamically grows (like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/65607605/12299030).

Comment: @Asperi this solved my problem, thank you! I posted an answer with the code that I used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Asperi suggested, `.frame(width: 28)` on an image will set them to all be the same width, preventing this issue.